# Select statement within if condition not working with additional parameters

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do this

```
SELECT 
  table1.*,
  table2.id as t2id 
FROM 
  table1 as t1 
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 
  ON t2.field1 = t1.field2 
  AND t1.field2 = 'value'
  AND IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE id = 10 > 0)
```

It error says

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 

'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE id = 10 > 0) LIMIT ' at line 1
```

I know the error is with the if condition as when I remove it, it works, but my thinking is the select will return a null value if it was not successful i.e. it didn't find anything in the table with id 10 from table2.

Comment: this is mysql statement, not mysqli

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the "then" part of your if.

It has too look like IF (condition, then, else), but you're just doing the condition without any output.

Try it that way:

```
AND IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE id = 10) > 0, 'true', 'false')
```

Comment: @Stephan how exactly do i do it ? IF(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE id = 10) = 'true' ?

Comment: exactly , or you can use it simple like `AND IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE id = 10) > 0, true, false)` this way the result of the `IF` is a boolean not a string and you don't need to compare it

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `IF`.

```
SELECT 
  table1.*,
  table2.id as t2id 
FROM 
  table1 as t1 
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 
  ON t2.field1 = t1.field2 
  AND t1.field2 = 'value'
  AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table2 WHERE id = 10) > 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (make sure that you exec the queries on the same session):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO @COUNTER FROM table2 WHERE id = 10 ;

SELECT 
  table1.*,
  table2.id as t2id 
FROM 
  table1 as t1 
INNER JOIN table2 as t2 
  ON t2.field1 = t1.field2 
  AND t1.field2 = 'value'
  AND @COUNTER > 0 ;
```